# How are client requests related to a specific session routed?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, server

Let's say you are using spring MVC in the backend, now imagine a client makes a request to the server, a session object for that request is made and saved in the server for a specific amount of time before it expires, now each time a individual request is made by that client the server remembers through the session object which client it is.

My question is that in a production setup there can be thousands of these servers in an application, what is responsible for making sure that any subsequent requests made by a client ends up going to the server that contains the session information about the client?

like let's say in an application where there are 5 servers 1,2,3,4,5. A client makes a request to the application and the request ends up going to server 4, when the request goes to server 4 a session is created for the client. Now imagine the client makes another(completely new) request to the server, how does the application know that the request should be routed to **server 4** where the session information for that client was stored previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application doesn't. There are two general approaches:

- "Sticky sessions", where the load balancer in front of the instances keeps track of the sessions and routes them to the same instances every time. This is quick and dirty, but it has the major downside of being fragile. For example, if an instance crashes or is shut down for upgrade or downscaling, you lose.
- Store the session information somewhere else. Spring makes this trivially easy with Spring Session. (I personally prefer to use Redis and JSON serialization.) In this case, a filter retrieves the session for each request and updates the stored version if necessary.

Comment: Or a combination of both, where requests get routed with sticky sessions to a server that has the session in memory or in a nearby cache, until that server gets overloaded or is brought down/crashes, after which another server loads the entire session from persistent storage.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sure, you can do a combination, but once you already have the "any server can serve the request" facility, anything else is just an attempt at performance improvement.